# Puedo utilizar los datos guardados en shared preferences en cualquier clase sin put extra?

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

Tengo esa duda, porque utilizo muchos fragments en mi app y me vendría genial almacenar unos editext en shared preferences y luego usarlos simplemente llamando a estos datos desde cualquier clase, sin put extra.

Comment: Exactamente esa es la idea, y la respuesta es **si**, simplemente inicializa tus preferencias en los activitys y listo, ya allí puedes acceder a los datos almacenados, agregar o eliminar datos en tus shared!!

Comment: Si, si creía que lo tenía claro pero llevo toda la mañana buscando el error de porque me daba como null una variable, y digo pues lo único que puede pasar es que no deje pasar info con shared, pero mi error era que eran distintas las Keys , tenía cambiado una cosa minúscula y me ha costado encontrarlo mucho xD Gracias igualmente

Comment: Si, se puede llamando simplemente a tus shared preferences y luego llamando la variable con su key.
Sabía que se podía hacer pero un fallo de variables me hizo dudar, de todas maneras espero que esto le sirva a algún dudoso como yo jajaja